# Subfolder in Python package not visible when installed

Tags: python, package

Given a Python package with the following structure.

[image]

Installed it with `pip`

```
pip install --upgrade git+git://github.com/balandongiv/driving_tools.git
```

The installed directory looks as below

[image]

As shown in figure above, the subfolder `sub_file` and the `nickname_override.py` are missing in the installation folder.

May I know what modification is required to amend this issue.

Modification to be made as per [Balaitous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68048129/6446053)

```
from setuptools import setup,find_packages

setup(name='ppackage',
    version='0.0.111',
    description='make life easier',
    author='testx',
    packages=['ppackage','ppackage.sub_file'],
)
```

Comment: Check gitignore. One more way. Right button of mouse and click Add from Git submenu

Comment: Hi @AndyPavlov, May I know check for what specifically, thanks

Comment: Please list your gitignore. Any way. Try to make any change at nickname_override.py and make commit from pycharm. Do you see any changes at commit/push window of pycharm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `packages` argument of `setup` fonction, all modules have to be explicitly mentioned. Module can be a python file or a folder containing `__init__.py`.

It is not recursive. Here you have two modules `ppackage` and `ppackage.sub_folder`.

See: https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages

So you should have:

```py
setup(
    name=...,
    packages=["ppackage", "ppackage.sub_folder"],
    ...
)
```

If you want to embed all modules in you package, you can use `find_packages`

```py
from setuptools import find_packages

setup(
    packages=find_packages(),
    ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but both approach is not working

Comment: On your screnhot, `setup.py` seems be be in `ppackage` while on github it is at top level. The good place is at toplevel.

Comment: Hi @Balai, neither suggestion is working, thanks. Have you ever confirm this on your side?

Comment: After forking to https://github.com/adelplanque/driving_tools seems working.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the installation folder

Comment: After `pip3 install git+http://github.com:adelplanque/driving_tools.git` into a fresh virtual env, `find env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ppackage -name "nickname*.py"` result in `env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ppackage/sub_file/nickname_override.py`.
packages list is `["ppackage", "ppackage.sub_file"]`, but `find_packages` should work too.

Comment: Please share the screenshot, I have tested this on Windows and Ubuntu, but fail to get the output as per your explanation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233980/discussion-between-balaitous-and-balandongiv).